# Kafka real time streaming vs Micro services

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Is there any minimum rate of message in gbps required to choose Kafka for real time streaming?

Can we handle really low rate of messages in Kafka?

Comment: I would say that there are no such restrictions and recommendations for use. Kafka used in many different cases.
But it seems to me that your question is extremely non-specific. You need to tell in more detail what problem you are trying to solve, and what options you are considering.

Comment: My source produces roughly 4000 to 5000 messages per day and  Kafka having able to handle huge volume of data with high through put,will it be able to handle such a low volume and the message rate also will be low?

Comment: Responding specifically to your question: Kafka is fully capable of handling a small stream. There will be no loss of performance.
In my projects, the Kafka is used both for very large data flows and for very small ones.
I hope I answered your question

Answer (score 2):

> My source produces roughly 4000 to 5000 messages per day and Kafka having able to handle huge volume of data with high through put,will it be able to handle such a low volume and the message rate also will be low?

Yes. And "Yes" not just for Kafka "Core" (brokers = storage, publish/subscribe), but also Yes for:

- Kafka producer and consumer clients (write messages and read messages, respectively)
- Kafka Connect (for integrating Kafka with other systems like MySQL, Elastisearch, S3)
- Kafka Streams (for writing processing applications in Java/Scala)
- KSQL (for writing processing applications in streaming SQL)